# Multiple client connections for one socket

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I have a socket based server which accepts client connections. The problem is server is able to accept only one client connection. I want it to accept multiple clients.

server code:

```
        class Conn extends Thread{
        ServerSocket ss;
        Socket s;
        public void run()
        {
            status.setText(status.getText()+"connecting");
            try{
            while(true)
            {
            ss=new ServerSocket(3000);
            s=ss.accept();
            Read r=new Read(s);
            r.start();
            }
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }            
    }
```

Comment: I think you'd be better off with MulticastSockets http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html

Comment: Try to narrow down the scope of your question a bit more - [we can't debug your code base for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135066/175248).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Conn` class, put something like:

```
try {
    ss = new ServerSocket(3000);
    while(true) {
        s = ss.accept();
        Read r = new Read(s);
        r.start();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Open the server socket, and in a loop, accept all incoming connections and process them starting a new thread.

Comment: Nop, socket creation is outside loop. Loop accepts all incoming connections and process them.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the connected clients in a list and then send the incoming String to all of them instead only sending it to the client who wrote the message

Comment: how to reply to all clients? at once

Comment: you can use just a simple for loop and send them one by one as you do now.